# mongodb increments the number though I decrement it?

Tags: mongodb

I incremented the sp_amount by 1.6 in the first query . I then decremented it to -1.6 it stills increased the value ! How to set this right ?

Query used to INCREMENT :

> db.userwalletcreditlogs.findOneAndUpdate({transaction_id :
>   "8zioepbvwx7ua7vxse2u01wcdi"},{$set:{stripe_transfer_id
>   :"tr_1BBkxaCOEurZs8WVkXBqJwUT"},$inc:{ sp_amount : 1.6}})

output:

> "sp_amount" : 181.6,
>     "stripe_transfer_id" :"tr_1BBkxaCOEurZs8WVkXBqJwUT",

Query used to DECREMENT:

> db.userwalletcreditlogs.findOneAndUpdate({transaction_id : "8zioepbvwx7ua7vxse2u01wcdi"},{$set:{stripe_transfer_id :"tr_1BBkxaCOEurZs8WVkXBqJwUT"},$inc:{ sp_amount : -1.6}})

output:

> "sp_amount" : 183.2,
>     "stripe_transfer_id" :"tr_1BBkxaCOEurZs8WVkXBqJwUT",

[HERE is the screenshot of my mongoshell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxy6d.png)

Comment: Can you give us some more to go on? Context, code examples, that sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` will return the object before applying the operations. See below for result:

```
> db.test.save({i: 0.0})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb"), "i" : 0 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb")}, {$inc: {i: 1.6} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb"), "i" : 0 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb")}, {$inc: {i: -1.6} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb"), "i" : 1.6 }
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df362e6ecc1229670714fb"), "i" : 0 }
```

If you want to get the object after the update has applied you need to pass in an option of `{returnNewDocument:true}`, see the same example below:

```
> db.test.save({i: 0.0})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd"), "i" : 0 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd")}, {$inc: {i: 1.6} }, {returnNewDocument:true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd"), "i" : 1.6 }
> db.test.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd")}, {$inc: {i: -1.6} }, {returnNewDocument:true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd"), "i" : 0 }
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59df37406ecc1229670714fd"), "i" : 0 }
>
```

For more information check out the documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#definition

Comment: Thank you . It helped me .!